# Can I open cocos studio .csd files with Cocos Creator

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos-studio

As you know Cocos Studio is not working on macOS Catalina the reason is that 32-Bit Apps 'Not Optimized for Your Mac' No Longer Working on macOS Catalina.
But I have bunch of cocos studio csd files, can I open them with Cocos Creator?

Comment: adding here a discussion about this topic https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/coco-studio-cancelled/28223/54